# Perl : constant & require

Tags: perl, include, constants, require

I have a config file (config.pl) with my constants :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Domain qw(hostname hostfqdn hostdomain domainname);

use constant URL => "http://".domainname()."/";
use constant CGIBIN => URL."cgi-bin/";
use constant CSS => URL."html/css/";
use constant RESSOURCES => URL."html/ressources/";
...
```

And I would like to use these constants in index.pl, so index.pl starts with :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use CGI;
require "config.pl";
```

how to use URL, CGI... in index.pl ?
Thanks,
Bye

---

*EDIT*
I found a solution :
config.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package Config;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Domain qw(hostname hostfqdn hostdomain domainname);

use constant URL => "http://".domainname()."/";
use constant CGIBIN => URL."cgi-bin/";
1;
```

index.pl

```
BEGIN {
    require "config.pm";
}
print Config::URL;
```

End

Comment: You're heading for trouble by having a constant called CGI and a package called CGI... much confusion will ensue!

Comment: Good remark ! Changing it right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do here is setup a Perl module that you can export from.

Place the following into 'MyConfig.pm':

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package MyConfig;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Domain qw(hostname hostfqdn hostdomain domainname);

use constant URL => "http://".domainname()."/";
use constant CGIBIN => URL."cgi-bin/";
use constant CSS => URL."html/css/";
use constant RESSOURCES => URL."html/ressources/";

require Exporter;
our @ISA = 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(hostname hostfqdn hostdomain domainname URL CGIBIN CSS RESSOURCES);
```

And then to use it:

```
use MyConfig;  # which means BEGIN {require 'MyConfig.pm'; MyConfig->import}
```

By setting `@ISA` to `Exporter` in the `MyConfig` package, you setup the package to inherit from `Exporter`.  `Exporter` provides the `import` method which is implicitly called by the `use MyConfig;` line.  The variable `@EXPORT` contains the list of names that `Exporter` should import by default.  There are many other options available in Perl's documentation and in the documentation for [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html)

Comment: Great answer! The explanation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
BEGIN {
    require "config.pl";
}
print URL;
```

or

```
require "config.pl";
print URL();
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me, no need export in config.pl and import in index.pl ?

Comment: @eouti, They actually work for me. What kind of error messages are you getting?

Comment: `constant` variables are actually subroutines. Without `package` declaration, they must be in the `main::` namespace.

Comment: Bareword "URL" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /var/www/cgi-bin/index.pl line 35.
Execution of /var/www/cgi-bin/index.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
BEGIN { require "config.pl"; }
```

And you must return a true value at the end of the required source. Usually:

```
1;
```

Although, on certain modules I have done:

```
print "My::Mod included...\n";
```

as the last statement in the file. And `print` returns a true anytime it prints a single character.

See [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html).

---

#### Troubleshooting

- It could be a directory issue. The `.pl` file must be in `@INC` or modified by a path to the file.

Try this:

```
perl -Mconfig.pl -e 1
```

If it fails, look at the error message. Actually, in any event, you should be getting more with strict and warnings than "Oops, it failed."

Answer (score 0):

You can't use barewords when you `use strict`.

A bareword is a essentially a variable name, without a sigil (`$,@,%,&,*`).

I suggest taking a look at the [`Readonly`](http://search.cpan.org/~roode/Readonly-1.03/Readonly.pm) module on CPAN for creating constants.

The `use constant` pragma has a bunch of arcane magic going on that can result in difficult to debug code, if you're not careful.

Comment: There's really nothing arcane or magical about the `constant` pragma.  It is purely syntactic sugar for creating constant subroutines.  `use constant X => 5;` is exactly the same as `sub X () {5}`.  In fact, I prefer the later because it serves as a reminder than the constants are in fact subroutines.

Comment: Maybe not 'magic' but certainly arcane, for the very reason that you prefer the latter: the sugar tries to make a subroutine look like a variable, but it doesn't behave like a variable in places that you would expect it to (like, within interpolated strings).